# C# : I have problem with createing implement interface object

Tags: c#, interface, namespaces, types

```
class MySql : IDatabase
{
    IDatabaseConnection con;
    public MySql() {
        this.con = new MySqlConnection();
        this.con.connect();
    }
}

class ScheduleServices
{
    IDatabase mysql;
    public ScheduleServices() {
       **this.mysql = new MySql();**
    }
}
```

Class ScheduleServices try to bulid MySql object which this class implement IDatabase interface. The error said

> MySql is a 'namespace' but is used like
>   a 'type'

How to build MySql as a object?

Comment: 25 questions at 25% accept - you should consider accepting more answers to get better responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference you think you have for the MySQL class refers to someting else (one of the `using` dependencies of ScheduleServices). Use a fully qualified name to reference your MySQL class if this is ambiguous in the ScheduleServices file, rename your MySQL class to avoid conflict, or use an alias using statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of the MySql class or use the full name (Namespace + class name) `new Namespace.MySql();`.  I would bet you have a naming conflict and that will resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to MySQL in your using statments, you have to resolve it in your code. MySql.MySql(). The compiler cannot disambiugate on its own.